# Can't see databases in android file explorer

Tags: android

I'm new for android programming and now working with SQLite databases. I have a simple sample and creating code :

```
public TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "timetracker.db", null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


}
```

And  in onCreate method in my activity class i create an openHelper for TimeTrackerOpenHelper:

```
    TimeTrackerOpenHelper openHelpler = new TimeTrackerOpenHelper(this);
```

I'm running the code and opening the file explorer following the path data/data/ but i can't see databases folder. why it isn't showed?

Comment: where is query  in onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)?

Comment: You need add db.execSQl("create table ..."); in onCreate() method

Comment: i created the database. I think creating table not important for seeing a database file. But i tried to create table as you said. Nothing has changed. Still i can't see database. Even i have used AVD.

Comment: What do you mean that you can't see the databases folder? How are you trying to view it?

Comment: my mistake.. I have looked at the wrong folder. Now i can see. I tried to view on Eclipse android file explorer. And i can see thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
I'm running the code and opening the file explorer following the path data/data/ but i can't see databases folder. why it isn't showed?
```

If you are testing on device then you **Can not** see DB file due to security unless your device is rooted.

If you want to see your DB file. you can use `ADV`